# How to prevent event handler attached in one userscript from interfering with another?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I have installed two separate userscripts, each requiring to invoke some code with `document.body.onkeydown`. However, I've noticed that with both userscripts enabled, only the latter event handler gets called.

Apparently, both userscripts are sharing the same DOM. This is contrary to my experience with Chrome extensions, where each Chrome extension has its own sandbox.

Either way, now how do I to fix this problem? I want both handlers to fire, and remain separate from each other.

I am executing my userscripts inside an IIFE with use strict mode enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `document.body.keydown` will set the callback to the `keydown` event. Setting it again will replace the old one. Hence the latter script's event callback gets fired.

Instead use, `document.body.addEventListener(<callback>)` in both so, both the events will present.

In the below example, first keydown will get overridden by the second one. The addEventListener will append an listener to the `keydown` event. So on pressing `a` only 3rd event fired. On pressing `b`, both 2nd and 3rd are fired.

This is because the events added via the older method is added as like attribute values. Like,

`<button id="show" onclick="show()">Click</button>`
Hence, it got replaced.

The `addEventListener` adds the listener to the list of EventListners of the DOM Object.

In the example I replaced the `onclick` attribute with the function `hide` via the older method, hence it calls only the `hide` method.

For more info, please refer [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
document.body.onkeydown = function(event){if(event.key=="a")console.log("keydown")};
document.body.onkeydown = function(event){if(event.key=="b")console.log("b keydown")};

document.body.addEventListener("keydown",function(){console.log("addEventListener")})

function show(){console.log("show")}
function hide(){console.log("hide")}

var element = document.getElementById("show");
element.onclick=hide;
```

```html
<button id="show" onclick="show()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change them to use

```
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(){ ... })
```

If they use the 'this' set in the `onkeydown` approach, you may need to make sure that is set correctly

```
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", (function(){ ... }).bind(document.body))
```

Comment: Thanks, `addEventListener` worked. Can you also tell why it works?